# Max value for Array.reserveCapacity(_:) in Swift

Tags: swift

What is the largest input that can be safely passed to `reserveCapacity(_:)`?

```
var a = [0]

a.reserveCapacity(Int.max)
// Results in EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) 

a.reserveCapacity(Int.max / 16)
// Results in EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
// Console log:
//   malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=4611686018427392000) failed (error code=3)
//   *** error: can't allocate region
//   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I could not find any way to handle either error.